# Is it possible to perform a resumable upload using Drive.Files.update()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have two partially downloaded files (in my Drive), which I had split earlier. Both of these files together form the whole file. My goal is to merge (i.e join) them in Google Drive using Apps Script.

What I have done so far?

I used `Drive.Files.insert` to upload the first part. Then I tried `Drive.Files.update` to upload the second part to the first part's. It however overwrites the file.

My question : Is it possible to join/append files using that method?

NB: I could join the file in my PC with `cat` or `type`

Here is a sample code of my work:

```
  var resource = {
    title : 'Demo'
  };

  var mediaData = f1.getBlob();
  //f1 contains the file 1

  var headers = {
    'Content-Length' : f1.getSize(),
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
     uploadType : 'resumable'
  }

  var file = Drive.Files.insert(resource, mediaData, {headers : headers});

  var fileId = file.id;

  resource = {
    title : 'New Demo',
    mimeType : 'pdf'
  };

  mediaData = f2.getBlob();
  //f2 contains file 2

  headers = {
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    uploadType : 'resumable'
  };

  var file = Drive.Files.update(resource, fileId, mediaData, {headers : headers});

  Logger.log(file.id + '\n' + file.fileSize);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, the resumable upload cannot be achieved using `Drive.Files.insert`. It seems that this is the current specification at Google side. By the way, can I ask you about the file size of `f1` and `f2` as the bytes? Because if `f1   f2 < 50 MB`, this can be achieve without using the resumable upload, and also, if the file of 'f1' is not the multiples of 256 KB (256 x 1024 bytes) in size, in order to achieve the resumable upload, it is required to adjust the each chunk. Before I propose the sample script for resumable upload, I would like to ask about the size.

Comment: @Tanaike Many thanks for the response. I have two situations. First: `f1 and f2` combined is less than 50 MB. But not a multiple of `256`. More specifically, `f1=30000 f2=32768`.  Second: `f1 = 50000000 bytes` , f2 will be some bytes extra.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your situation from your replying. Can I ask you about the detail of your replying?

Comment: @Tanaike I have two questions. 1. What is the procedure when `f1 and f2 < 50 MB`? 2. Can you show a sample script taking the size conveniently? .

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `1. What is the procedure when f1 and f2 < 50 MB?`, I cannot understand what you want. About `2. Can you show a sample script taking the size conveniently?`, I have no script for this now. I apologize for this. When I could correctly understand about your question, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize that I couldn't resolve your issue soon. This is due to my poor skill.

Comment: @Tanaike From your first comment `Because if f1 f2 < 50 MB, this can be achieve without using the resumable upload`. How to do that?

Comment: Now I noticed that `+` was removed at `f1 f2 < 50 MB`. In this case, if `f1 + f2 < 50 MB`, this can be achieve without using the resumable upload. I deeply apologize that I miswrote `f1 f2 < 50 MB` instead of `f1 + f2 < 50 MB` in my comment.

Comment: @Tanaike So, what is the procedure for files `f1 + f2 < 50 MB` ?

Comment: If the file size of "file A" + "file B" is less than 50 MB, one file can be created by merging the byte array retrieved from each file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213674/discussion-between-tyler-rake-and-tanaike).

Comment: @Tanaike I have moved the comments, as suggested by Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quoting Tanaike's comments as answer**.

> Unfortunately, in the current stage, the resumable upload cannot be achieved using Drive.Files.insert

Also, if the size of all the files together is less than 50 MB:

> If the file size of "file A" + "file B" is less than 50 MB, one file can be created by merging the byte array retrieved from each file.