# Using Resumable Upload to upload large video size on Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, webhooks

I built a webhook to send Zoom Recordings to Google Drive. The webhook works properly. However, the file is about 500,000,000 bytes. I believe I need to use Resumable Upload method to upload a full video and avoid Status 500 on Zoom side.

Below is my code so far:

```js
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(download_url + '?access_token=' + download_token);
    var getfile = response.getBlob();
    file = {
      title : name,
      mimeType : file_type.toLowerCase()
    };
    
    var mainFolders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(SessionFolderName);
    if (!mainFolders.hasNext()) {
      DriveApp.createFolder(SessionFolderName);
      mainFolders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(SessionFolderName);
    }
    
    mainFolder = mainFolders.next();
    
    var accFolders = mainFolder.getFoldersByName(account);
    if (!accFolders.hasNext()) {
      mainFolder.createFolder(account);
      accFolders = mainFolder.getFoldersByName(account);
    }
    
    accFolder = accFolders.next();
    
    var meetingFolders = accFolder.getFoldersByName(name);
    if (!meetingFolders.hasNext()) {
      accFolder.createFolder(name);
      meetingFolders = accFolder.getFoldersByName(name);
    }
    
    meetingFolder = meetingFolders.next();
```

I'm still struggling on how to start with the resumable upload. Please give me some advice.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: About the resumable upload using Google Apps Script, is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/61756742/7108653

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thank you for your response, it's very helpful. However, I'm not sure about a few things. What mimeType will be for video file type? How can I upload the file to a specific folder? A bigger question will be, based on your code, the file is already created.  For my case, the file hasn't been created yet, how can I create the FileObj? Thanks again for helping me with my problems!

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `What mimeType will be for video file type?`, I'm not sure about the file type you use. 2. About `How can I upload the file to a specific folder?`, you can check [the official document](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create). 3. About `A bigger question will be, based on your code, the file is already created. For my case, the file hasn't been created yet, how can I create the FileObj?`, I cannot understand.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, it's the mp4 file. From the example, i can see that you created an object for using at the resumable upload (Step 1). I'm not sure the purpose of it. If you can explain it, I would very appriciate.

Comment: Thank you for replying. `video/mp4` can be used as the mimeType of mp4 file. In order to achieve the resumable upload, as the step 1, it is required to retrieve the location of URL, at that time, only the file metadata is sent. As the step 2, the file data is uploaded. In this case, each data size is required to be the multiples of 262,144 bytes. You can see the detail of resumable upload at [the official document](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads#resumable).

Comment: Sorry if I'm wrong, but I think Step 2 is where you retrieve the location of URL and step 3 is where you upload the file. I'm not quite sure about step 1.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, unfortunately, I cannot understand about the step 1, 2 and 3 you are thinking. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: No you are great, I'm apologized for confusing you. On your example that you posted on the other post. I saw you made 3 steps: // 1. Create an object for using at the resumable upload. // 2. Retrieve "location" for starting the resumable upload. // 3. Upload each file and merge them. I understand the purpose of number 2 and 3. I'm not sure about number 1.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand about your replying. About the step 1 of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61756742), the object for merging 2 files is created. The object is used for the resumable upload. In your situation, where is the file you want to upload in? I think that it is required to prepare such object for your situation.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, I want to save it in the specific folder on Google Drive depends on the name of the video. As you can see my code, I use UrlFetchApp.fetch to get the video from the Download_URL then getBlob. How can I create an object for my video in this case? Can you please suggest?

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, there is the large size file in an URL. You want to download the file from the URL and put it to the specific folder in your Google Drive. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Hi Tanaike,  yes that's what I want to do.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your case, when the large file (in your question, it's 500 MB.) is downloaded, it is required to run [the partial download](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests). And the downloaded each files are required to be uploaded with the resumable upload. At first, I think that it is required to check whether the server that the file is put can be downloaded with the partial download. How about this? Unfortunately, I cannot know about it. Because I'm not the administrator of the server. I apologize for this.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, is it possible to just use the Download_URL link is provided by Zoom webhook to save the file to Google Drive? I'm not using any server right now, so I don't think I can run the partial download. I'm just using the `code` UrlFetchApp.fetch `code` to fetch the Download_URL, then getBlob, then save the file. The file is saved, I can view it, but the size is only 50MB. I'm so sorry for asking a lot of basic questions, I'm very new to Google Script and Javascript.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I'm not sure whether "the Download_URL link is provided by Zoom webhook" can be done the partial download. This is due to my poor experience. I deeply apologize for this. In your environment, can you confirm it? If the partial download cannot be achieved, your goal cannot be achieved with the Google Apps Script. In that case, I think that it is required to download the file from the server and upload it to Google Drive using the script at the local PC.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, I think you're right, that is what I was going to do at the beginning, but I just tried to skip the server part to see if it's possible to make it go straight to Google Drive. I guess I will have to do some more research on how to using the download_url to download the video to local PC and upload it to Google Drive. Can you suggest any app to achieve it or how should I start? Thank you so much for all of your comments, I learned a lot!

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I'm not sure about an application for directly achieving your goal. This is due to my poor experience. I apologize for this.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, that's ok, you helped me a lot. I very appreciate it!

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, it's me again. I made a Python script that download the video to my local PC and I kind of know how to use Python to do Resumable Upload method. The only thing that I'm struggling is how to get the access_token. I have created the OAuth Credentials on the Google Console, but having hard time to generate the access_token using Python. Can you please give me some advise? Thank you so much, you guided me through most of this project.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from your replying, I couldn't image your wholes script. This is due to my poor English skill. I have to apologize for this. When you want to use the python script and authorize the scopes for using Drive API, you can see the Quickstart for python at [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python).

Comment: @AnhNguyen Regarding the zoom recording, can you download them by parts by specifying the range? After reading various related posts, I think it is a two step process: in the **first step**, you need to fetch various parts of the video (each of 50 MB or less), and **second step**, is where you upload again to your drive using resumable upload. You have to fetch each part as mentioned in the first step. Let's say the video is of 240 MB, your parts are of 50,50,50,50,40 MB. But it depends on whether partial download is supported or not.

Comment: @AnhNguyen If you succeed in the first step i.e you are able to partial download the whole video into parts, you can proceed to the second step which is given in the answer of the comment given above. I mean [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61756742/how-to-upload-an-existing-file-in-drive-to-drive-using-apps-script)